# Molecular script add-on will not run

Tags: add-on, error

I've installed the Molecular Script add-on on a 64 bit PC running Win7.
I do not have admin rights on the PC.
I made sure to use the latest 64-bit version of the add-on and I am using Blender 2.77.
The file cmolcore.pyd is located inside the "Molecular"-folder here:
C:\Users\mwl\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\molecular

When I click the "Start Molecular Simulation" I get the following error:
File"C:\Users\mwl\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\Scripts\addons\molecular_init_.py",line600,in execute mol_report=cmolcore.init(mol_exportdata)
NameError:name'cmolcore' is not defined.

I do not have Microsoft Visual C++ installed on this PC

Any ideas what could be wrong?

The same add-on runs problem free on my 64-bit home PC which runs Win10, and of which I am the administrator.

Kind regards

Ryosei

[image]

[image]

Hi again aliasguru
I posted an image of the location and version of my add-on.
I'm afraid everything looks as it should  :-(

Comment: There's something off with your installation. Maybe you had an older version of the addon installed, and it hasn't been removed yet. The 1.03 version which is compatible with Blender 2.77 should be located at C:\Users\mwl\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\Scripts\addons\molecular\ __init__.py  (note that there is a subfolder called `molecular`. The error you posted indicates the file is in the `addons` directory. In the same folder `molecular` you MUST have a file called `cmolcore.pyd`.

Comment: Hi aliasguru
Thanks for your quick reply.
I did in fact install an older version of the add-on and later deleted it.

Comment: Hi again aliasguru
Hi aliasguru
Thanks for your quick reply.
I did in fact install an older version of the add-on and later deleted it.
Inside the "Molecular" folder I have one folder called "_pycache_" and two files: "_init_.py" and "cmolcore.pyd"

I added a screendump of the "Molecular" folder contents above.

Comment: hmmm the files should be allright, there is still a source of complication though: in Blender it is possible to have the same addon in multiple folders. Please open your UserPreferences, go to `Add-ons`, look for `molecular`, and check a) which version it reports (should be 1.0.3) and b) which installation folder is printed under `File`

Comment: Hi aliasguru
I've posted the info you asked for.
I guess it's bad news that everything looks as it should.

Do you think the reason could be that I also run Blender 2.78 portable from a USB stick on the same PC?

Comment: Running from a portable drive should not be an issue. Blender is designed to work this way. We're running Blender off a network drive without installing it locally, and also use shared preferences (including molecular) there. Also, we don't work with Admin rights, so that should also not be an issue. If you only see one single molecular addon in the list, then I'm runing out of ideas. What you post is fine and correct.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply aliasguru.
I'm sorry that we cannot find the source of the glitch. Would really like to make the script run on this PC.
I've also posted the situation on PyroEvils website but have not heard from him yet.
Think I should report a bug from within Blender?

Kind regards
Ryosei

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

It turned out that I did not read PyroEvils instructions before installing the add-on.
I did have Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable installed.
But in order to for the Molecular add-on 1.03 to run you need Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable.
I got ITServicedesk to install the 2015-version and now the Molecular add-on runs as it should.

I made sure to make a donation to Jean-Francois.